# The probability of remaining cups of soda in an urn according to a uniform distribution

Tags: probability

Suppose we have that there is a $50$ cup soda urn and that someone checks the urn every now and then to see how many cups remain. Suppose that the number of cups that remain is a Uniform random variable. I would like to find the probability that on a "checking", that there remains greater than 30 cups and the mean of the cups remaining at any instance.

This is an easy problem but I am wondering if I am correct. I assume a continuous uniform distribution (should it be discrete?) and so the probability of $P(X>30) = 1-P(X \leq 30) = 1- \frac{30}{50}$ and also the mean is $E(X) = \frac{0+50}{2} = 25$. I am wondering if using $X \sim Unif(0,50)$ is the correct approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uniform distribution is a continuous distribution which is not possible in this case. Assuming that by uniform distribution it is meant that there is equal probability of each outcome $1 \le i \le 50$ the expectation will be $1/50 \sum_{i=1}^{50} i= 25.5 $